# Creating table of contents with Markdown nested inside HTML

Tags: html, markdown, pandoc

Whenever I have markdown inside HTML tags, it doesn't get generated with the table of contents option. For example,

```
#Test

##Test2

Hello there!

#Test3

##Test4

<div>

#hello

</div>
```

Outputs:

```
<nav id="TOC">
<ul>
<li><a href="#test">Test</a><ul>
<li><a href="#test2">Test2</a></li>
</ul></li>
<li><a href="#test3">Test3</a><ul>
<li><a href="#test4">Test4</a></li>
</ul></li>
</ul>
</nav>
<h1 id="test">Test</h1>
<h2 id="test2">Test2</h2>
<p>Hello there!</p>
<h1 id="test3">Test3</h1>
<h2 id="test4">Test4</h2>
<div>
<h1>hello</h1>
</div>
```

The command line I'm using is:

```
pandoc -f markdown -t html5 --toc -s test.md
```

Is it possible to have table of contents include markdown that's nested in HTML?

Comment: http://blog.yoavram.com/citations-in-markdown-using-pandoc/ says _..the TOC is inserted by Pandoc only if the `standalone` option is given or a suitable template is given.._ and a description of the `--standalone` and templates is available at [Pandoc User's Guide → Templates](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#templates). Does it help?

Answer (score 1):

As I just had to solve the same problem, I thought I would share it.

Pandoc author specified in [this issue](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/997#issuecomment-31503690) the reasonning behind this behaviour.

He also specifies the workarounds, actually. Simply replace the `<div>` by `<article>`. In your case, it would become:

```
#Test

##Test2

Hello there!

#Test3

##Test4

<article>

#hello

</article>
```

with your command line, it gives me

```
<nav id="TOC">
<ul>
<li><a href="#test">Test</a><ul>
<li><a href="#test2">Test2</a></li>
</ul></li>
<li><a href="#test3">Test3</a><ul>
<li><a href="#test4">Test4</a></li>
</ul></li>
<li><a href="#hello">hello</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
<h1 id="test">Test</h1>
<h2 id="test2">Test2</h2>
<p>Hello there!</p>
<h1 id="test3">Test3</h1>
<h2 id="test4">Test4</h2>
<article>
<h1 id="hello">hello</h1>
</article>
```